# systemManager.addEventListener of sub application is not working in main application

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder

i used `systemManager.addEventListener` in sub application and it is working well but when i load sub application into main application through swfloader it does not work.

Comment: Can you post some code that shows us what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

If you're loading a module into a main application, the module is 'sandboxed' so that it can't interfere with the main app. If you want it to do so however, you need to set the applicationDomain of the ModuleLoader like this:

```
<mx:ModuleLoader applicationDomain="{ApplicationDomain.currentDomain}" url="..." />
```

Comment: In that case, use the `trustContent` property and set it to 'true'

Comment: systemManager.addEventListner..........what we can use by replacing system manager